# Aligning divs in <td> to top of <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

Update: added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WgzgF/11/

I have a table with a bunch of `<td>`. Each td has a div `.tdcont` which is like a wrapper of all content in that td. In `.tdcont`, I have 2 groups of divs `.alwaystop` and `.below-at`.

```
<td class="table-td">
   <div class="tdcont">
      <div class="alwaystop">           
         <div class="at1">at1</div>
         <div class="at2">at2</div>
         <div class="at3">at3</div>
      </div>            
      <div class="below-at">
         <div class="bat1">bat1</div>
         <div class="bat2">bat2</div>
         <div class="bat3">bat3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

The problem I'm having is that `alwaystop` is supposed to align itself to the top border of the cell and `below-at` is supposed to come right under it like this

```
_____________________________________________________
at1 at2 at3       | at1 at2 at3     | at1 at2 at3    |
bat1 bat2 bat3    | bat1 bat2 bat3  | bat1 bat2 bat3 |
small image here  | big image here  |                |
                  | is taking lots  |                |
                  | of space        |                |
__________________|_________________|________________|
```

What I'm finding is that `alwaystop` and `below-at` center themselves vertically like you see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WgzgF/11/ so if one of the adjacent cells in this row is long, `alwaystop` centers itself to this row's height like this

```
_____________________________________________________
                  | at1 at2 at3     |                |
                  | bat1 bat2 bat3  |                |
at1 at2 at3       | big image here  | at1 at2 at3    |
bat1 bat2 bat3    | is taking lots  | bat1 bat2 bat3 |
small image here  | of space        |                |
__________________|_________________|________________|
```

What I want to do is make `alwaystop` always start from the top of the cell regardless of adjacent cells' heights, then the `below-at` comes under it. How can I do this?

I should add that I have the content of `alwaystop` is floated left, so is the content of `below-at`, so they're supposed to be like 2 rows inside that td.

```
.at1, .at2, .at3{ 
   float:left; 
}
.bat1, .bat2, .bat3{ 
   float:left; 
}
```

The css for alwaystop and below-at is empty. I tried a whole bunch of stuff like vertical-align and absolute positioning, but nothing worked and I just gave up and deleted them.

```
.alwaystop{ 
}
.below-at{
}
```

Comment: what is this stuff that you are trying to display in a table as divs but still looks like a table?

Comment: Can you supply the CSS for .alwaystop and .below-at ?

Comment: Have you tried display:table-cell or display:table-row or anything of that family?

Comment: Yeah, please post the rest of your CSS. Our noses aren't that good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have demonstrated as @Damien suggested in the comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnrietteC/WgzgF/

And it seems to be doing what you want, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle to show you what I mean. It's not aligning correctly. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/WgzgF/11/ Just added more <td> and extra content to demo my point.

Comment: This is the closest I can come up with for now: http://jsfiddle.net/AnrietteC/WgzgF/21/

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
.table-td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I thought that vertical-align was dependant on the parent object being `display: inline;` ? Within a table, one must valign the content, not the cell, or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, it is working. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/WgzgF/254/. You might be right though, I'm not sure.

Comment: **Edit:** valign = vertical-align, not to be confused with `<tr valign="top">` as this is no longer valid HTML as of HTML5. CSS is recommended for forward compatibility.